# Is it possible to to randomly redirect users using IIS URLRewrite?

Tags: rewrite

If I would like to randonly redirect users to different parts of the page to conduct testing is it possible to do so with rewrite rules and in particular with IIS URL Rewrite tool?

Comment: Have you found a solution? I need to implement the same, slice some users to beta version of our web app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to have anchors to each "random" place and do a 301 redirect, which engines can do, but isn't really re-writing.

A better solution would be to use JavaScript. A quick jquery function could achieve this, assuming the browser has JavaScript enabled.

Comment: When you say anchors, what do you mean exactly by them?

Comment: Anchors are points in a webpage that the browser can automatically locate (scroll to), and they're indicated by having a # at the end of the url. For example - http://serverfault.com/questions/322751/is-it-possible-to-to-randomly-redirect-users-using-iis-urlrewrite/322762#322762 - that jumps you directly to this answer, because the question has an anchor on it with the ID of 322762, and it appears after the # in the URL